# Invalid signature error on rest-api retrieve products

Tags: rest-api, oauth

I want to retrieve **all products** from magento website through **rest api**.

I am trying to connect to my Magento API but keep getting an invalid signature error.

i have all integration details like `Consumer Key`, `Consumer Secret`, `Access Token` & `Access Token Secret`.

i am working with Oauth to retrieve products but it shows me Invalid Signature error all time. the `oauth_signature` i am creating with Oauth not matching with the default functions creating `oauth_signature` of magento.

[image]

Comment: Did you find solution to solve this issue. please let me know.

Comment: What is your end point? because seems it is wrong.

Comment: in postman uncheck "encode signature" option.